# What do the golden butterflies symbolize?

Tags: the-forgotten-city

I'm just starting to explore the city in "The Forgotten City" (PC, via Steam), and I've noticed a few places there are golden butterflies hovering in certain areas.

Here's one example, where they're hovering over a pile of straw holding some goose eggs.

[image: Golden butterflies over a pile of straw]

I picked up the eggs, but the butterflies are still there -- so I'm wondering what exactly their purpose is? I've seen no in game hint about this.

The other place I saw the butterflies so far was in caves. I crawled into a a small room, and there was some ivy hanging off the wall; there were butterflies at the top of the ivy. When I interacted with the ivy, the context help said something along the lines of "if it could support my weight, I could use this to climb up." In that case, I couldn't figure out how to climb up, so I figured it might show up later.

When I tried googling, I found some guides like [this one](https://eip.gg/the-forgotten-city/guides/walkthrough/) which says:

> It’s also good to remember that at any point while playing, you can press [X] and some golden butterflies will guide you to your next objective (assuming you have one selected, and it isn’t hidden).

That doesn't seem to be relevant, since I haven't pushed any trigger key (and 'x' doesn't do anything, but that might be something poorly mapped from one of the console versions.)

Other sites mention that if you break the golden rule, there will be golden butterflies leading you back to the shrine (and the time portal.) But that's not relevant here either, because I've not broken the golden rule and the judgement isn't coming down on us.

What are these butterflies? What do they signify, and should I be interacting with them in some way? (Eg do they indicate question objective? easy-to-miss collectables? easter eggs??)

Please no spoilers, I've only just started this game and am still working through the early bits of the main quest line(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a contextual clue that there's something important there.

All well-designed games give similar hints, though usually they're more subtle than this *(special lighting, colors, outlines, paths on the ground, etc.)*.

> When I interacted with the ivy, the context help said something along the lines of "if it could support my weight, I could use this to climb up." [..] I figured it might show up later.

Yes, it will show up later.